# Append TextView of another activity through main

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm trying to create a game log, to show what happened on each round of the game. The log is in another activity but I want to be updated constantly with whatever the player does. A player just presses buttons that do certain things. It's too much code to post, but I have made a new bundle, and an intent.

In MainActivity.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Intent GameLogSwitch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GameLog.class);
```

I am trying to put this to send to the other activity but I don't know if you can put variables in it. otherwise it works with simple words such as ("key","It works")

```
GameLogSwitch.putExtra("Break","---BREAK---"+"\n"+Player1Name+": "+GreenResult.getText()+"("+GrTop1+","+GrTop2+","+GrTop3+")"+"\n"+Player2Name+": "+RedResult.getText()+"("+RdTop1+","+RdTop2+","+RdTop3+")");
```

and then of course I have this when the gamelog button is pressed

```
startActivity(GameLogSwitch);
```

Now in Gamelog.class i have this.

```
package com.example.adam.snookerproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GameLog extends AppCompatActivity {
        private TextView GameLogText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_log);
        GameLogText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GameLogText);
        Intent GameLogSwitch = getIntent();
        String myString = GameLogSwitch.getStringExtra("Break");
        GameLogText.append(myString);
    }
}
```

I have a couple of questions. First, why does append only work once with my string when I start the activity i.e when I go back and press the same button again it won't write the same thing again underneath?

Secondly, it doesn't seem to work for my "Break" key, does this have to do with the fact that there are variables in the text I'm sending? It only works for simple text like `GameLogSwitch.putExtra("key","It works");`

There must be an easier way to do this! Thank you.

UPDATE 1: The answer from Drv does seem to work, but when I try to do `GameLogText.append(AppConstants.log)` it just replaces everything in the textview no matter how many times I press the button. I think the activity is just resetting each time I start it again. Any way around this?

Comment: tl;dr . It'd probably be best that you look into EventBus library, it'll make your life a whole lot easier because it allows you to asynchronously send data from any place to any place.

Comment: http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: hmm ill take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a global string in Constants class and use it wherever you want:

```
  public class AppConstants{

        public static String log="";
  }
```

Edit the string in the class where you are sending it in intent:

```
  AppConstants.log="---BREAK---"+"\n"+Player1Name+": "+GreenResult.getText()+"("+GrTop1+","+GrTop2+","+GrTop3+")"+"\n"+Player2Name+": "+RedResult.getText()+"("+RdTop1+","+RdTop2+","+RdTop3+")";
```

And use it in your class as:

```
  package com.example.adam.snookerproject;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class GameLog extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView GameLogText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_log);

       GameLogText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GameLogText);

       //get your log here using AppConstants.log
   }
  }
```

Comment: This does seem to work for the first part of my problem thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getContext() instead of getApplicationContext, then check your string in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Use Callback or Interface. Fire the Interface from the Main Activity and Implement the call Interface in the Activity where you want the Textview to be Updated. Inside that method Update your Text View.

[Read here More about Communication between Activity Activity and Fragment Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

I managed to append using `"\n"+AppConstants.log` at the end of each output.